# How to fix MessageFormatter returning incorrect date formatted?

Tags: php, date, formatting, strftime

I have this simple code, which used to work correctly before:

```
<?php
$dateFormatted = \MessageFormatter::formatMessage(
    'en_US', "{0, date, d MMMM YYYY}", [new \DateTime()]
);

var_dump($dateFormatted); // 28 December 2019
```

But from Dec 29th, 2019 it shows next year's date:

```
var_dump($dateFormatted); // 29 December 2020
```

And this happens for every year I checked until 2050. As far as I know, it only happens on last december days, but I'm not sure. 2018 year unaffected. Why this happens and is there any fix to it?

php version 7.1

Upd: looks like `strftime` has same problem

Upd2: `strftime` show correct year with `%Y` but not with `%G`

Comment: Its really good question. but no problem with `echo strftime("%d %B %Y");` what your example of `strftime`?

Comment: yeah, `echo strftime("%d %B %Y");` returns correct date, which is strange, because `%G` still returns next year. Thanks for pointing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortinatly the documention of `MessageFormatter` is not explain about `date` formating. but i found how to fix it. you can use lower `y`. try:

```
$dateFormatted = \MessageFormatter::formatMessage(
    'en_US', "{0, date, d MMMM y}", [new \DateTime()]
);
echo $dateFormatted; // 30 December 2019
```

And for `strftime` you can use `strftime("%d %B %Y")`. 
I think this issue come from the [`ISO_8601`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard of format

Answer (score 2):

Uppper case `Y` means **year of "Week of Year"** ([reference](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime)), according to ISO-8601:1988 week number definition in which the last days of calendar year typically belong to the first week of next year. You want lower case `y`:

```
<?php
$dateFormatted = \MessageFormatter::formatMessage(
    'en_US', "{0, date, d MMMM YYYY} / {0, date, d MMMM yyyy}", [new \DateTime('2019-12-29')]
);
var_dump($dateFormatted);
```

```
string(37) " 29 December 2020 /  29 December 2019"
```

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I thought that 2018 is unaffected, but was wrong, checked it for 29th, which happened to be saturday, so not new week